Is the Microsoft workbook operation status based on the long-running session of the workbook or the specific operation performed through old session?
According to Microsoft documentation, when we try to create a long-running session, an "Accepted" (response code: 202) response is returned if there is any long-running operation running for the particular workbook. In this response, they include a Location header with an operation API URL to check the operation status. The status values from this URL can be notStarted, running, succeeded, or failed.
Could you explain if these status values are based on the currently running session or an operation performed through an old session?
when the aforementioned state will occur.
